# Scenario.embed error : Cannot resolve method 'embed' in 'Scenario'

Tags: java, cucumber

I have a cucumber project. If I want to take screenshots I want to embed it using the following.
  `scenario.embed(((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES), "image/png");` however I get an error with `embed` - `Cannot resolve method 'embed' in 'Scenario'`

Part of my hooks file

```
 @After
    public void teardownAndScreenshotOnFailure(Scenario scenario){
        try {
            if(driver != null && scenario.isFailed())
            {
                scenario.embed(((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES), "image/png");
            }
            if(driver != null)
            {
                driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
                driver.quit();
                driver = null;
            }
            ....
```

I have imported the following:

```
import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.Scenario;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
```

I am using the latest version of cucumber in my POM.xml : [6.9.1](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=cucumber)

I am not sure why I get this issue, Ive tried downgrading my cucumber, google the error but shomehow embed is not working. [image: Error of embed]

Comment: @Stultuske - Wow quite rude. I was following examples from https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/browser-automation/?sbsearch=Screenshots#tips-and-tricks where they clearly state `scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png")`. I was purely asking why `embed` is not working if there is tons of documentation that uses it,

Comment: quite rude? you ask us to debug your code. Correction: image of a code. You don't mention the type of scenario. Based on your import statements, I can only guess it's of type Scenario. If you are following that tutorial, has it come to you that maybe you should ask your question there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the Java documentation for 6.9.1 . You can use attach() method.

**embed()** method was deprecated and its removed from 6.0 [Documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.cucumber/cucumber-java/latest/io/cucumber/java/Scenario.html).

```
public void attach​(byte[] data, String mediaType, String name)
Attach data to the report(s).
 
 // Attach a screenshot. See your UI automation tool's docs for
 // details about how to take a screenshot.
 scenario.attach(pngBytes, "image/png", "Bartholomew and the Bytes of the Oobleck");
 
 
To ensure reporting tools can understand what the data is a mediaType must be provided. For example: text/plain, image/png, text/html;charset=utf-8.



Parameters:
data - what to attach, for example an image.
mediaType - what is the data?
name - attachment name
```